# Loading Multiple Jars on Windows - JNI JNI_CreateJavaVM

Tags: java, c++, jar, java-native-interface, classpath

I'm creating a JVM within my C++ application for windows, and I'm unable to convince it to load multiple jars.

My C++ code:

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::string & classPath) {
    classPath = "-cp "+classPath;   // <--  Won't work with any path or single jar
    //classPath = "-Djava.class.path="+classPath; <-- Only works with single jar
    jvmOptions[0].optionString = (char *)classPath.c_str();
    jvmOptions[1].optionString = "-Xms8m";
    jvmOptions[2].optionString = "-Xmx24m";
    jvmArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    jvmArgs.options = jvmOptions;
    jvmArgs.nOptions = 3;
    jvmArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
    int jvmInitResult = CreateJavaVM( &jvm, (void**)&environment, &jvmArgs);

    if( jvmInitResult >= 0 ) {
        jclass loadedClass = environment->FindClass( MyClassName.c_str() );
          .....
```

If I pass a path via my `classPath` variable to a single JAR, such as `"C:\path\myjar.jar"`, the `jclass` variable is located fine.  However, my Java class requires additional JARs to function, so I need to pass more than one JAR to the `jvmOptions`.  When I try to pass the second, or third JAR, in any of the following ways, the `FindClass` call now fails.

```
C:\path\myjar.jar    <--------- FindClass SUCCESS; can't use due to missing jars
C:\path\myjar.jar;C:\path\secondjar.jar  <-----FindClass FAIL
C:\path\myjar.jar:C:\path\secondjar.jar  <-----FindClass FAIL
C:\path\*  <-----FindClass FAIL
C:\path\*.jar  <-----FindClass FAIL
"C:\path\myjar.jar;C:\path\secondjar.jar"  <-----FindClass FAIL
"C:\path\myjar.jar:C:\path\secondjar.jar"  <-----FindClass FAIL
```

I assume there is another option I'm not thinking of, but this is driving me nuts.

Comment: `jvmOptions[0].optionString = (char *)("-Djava.class.path="+classPath).c_str();` - First of all, you don't want that to be modified, and secondly, the pointer dangles after that statement.

Comment: I agree, and that step is temporary, but I needed a quick dynamic way to change this without a recompile while I find the correct format.  The variable gets passed in as a command line argument.

Comment: The line @chris commented on will never work because `"-Djava.class.path="+classPath` will create a temporary `std::string` that gets destroyed at the end of that statement. `jvmOptions[0].optionString` points to invalid memory thereon. Maybe you want to use `classPath.insert(...)` instead.

Comment: I've edited the above to remove the temporary string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to not use windows file separators when passing the argument to the program.  The \ ends up getting escape sequenced with one or more \ .  Changing the argument to unix style file separators correctly loads all of the jars within a directory.

eg:

```
MyApp "classpath"
MyApp C:\pathtojars\  <-- fails
MyApp C:/pathtojars/  <-- works
```

Fixed code:

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::string & classPath )
{
   classPath = "-Djava.class.path="+classPath;
   jvmOptions[0].optionString = (char *)classPath.c_str();
   jvmOptions[1].optionString = "-Xms8m";
   jvmOptions[2].optionString = "-Xmx24m";
   jvmArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
   jvmArgs.options = jvmOptions;
   jvmArgs.nOptions = 3;
   jvmArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
   int jvmInitResult = CreateJavaVM( &jvm, (void**)&environment, &jvmArgs);

   if( jvmInitResult >= 0 )
   {
       jclass loadedClass = environment->FindClass( MyClassName.c_str() );
        .....
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think that using `/` is really the solution. I'm currently having issues with a classpath containing a wildcard character and Google takes me to this web page. What I'm sure is that using `-cp` doesn't work, using `*` (wildcard to include all JARs) doesn't work, and that both `"/"` and `"\"` do work on Windows. I've tested this with Java 6, 7, and 8. But if you use `"\"` directly in a C/C++ string, don't forget to protect it: `"dir\\file"` vs `"dir\file"`. 

As for `*`, it seems that it should be manually expanded, see `JLI_WildcardExpandClasspath()` in `java.c`.

Comment: @xav I tried with and without the escape sequencing; Only successful option was using unix-style path separation.  Other option would be to load the jars via Extension Class Loading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html

Comment: Strange... which OS and JRE are you using? For me it's Win7-64 bits with Java 6/7/8, 32/64 bits. I compile my EXE file with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @xav Win7 32/64 bit w Java 6/7.  Everything compiled with gcc/g++ MinGW

Comment: You have to manually expand "*" on Windows and use ";" as path separator in classpath.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `-cp` to set the class path.  I suspect `-Djava.class.path=` won't do what you think it should.

Comment: Switched it to -cp and still no go.  `classPath = "-cp "+classPath;  jvmOptions[0].optionString = (char *)classPath.c_str();`

Comment: @Samhain `-cp` and `the-classpath` are two arguments.

Comment: Modified to pass 4 jvmOptions, first one being -cp, second one being the path to my jars, or the path to a jar.  No success.  `jvmOptions[0].optionString = "-cp";
    jvmOptions[1].optionString = (char *)classPath.c_str();
    jvmOptions[2].optionString = "-Xms8m";
    jvmOptions[3].optionString = "-Xmx24m";`

Comment: Figured out the issue.  When passing the classpath via command line arguments, it is getting played with due to windows' file separator: \.  If I use the -Djava.class.path= option, with a hard coded file path using a unix style file separator, /, everything works as intended and all of the jars within the directory are loaded without issue.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Samhain See my comment below, I don't think that using `"/"` instead of `"\"` really helps