# JNI JVM Invocation Classpath

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, cygwin

I am writing a small C program using Cygwin that launches a Java Virtual Machine (libraries I am using require POSIX environment).  So far, I have been able to get it to work as long as I place all of my classes in the same folder as the executable.  However, I want to specify an actual JAR file that contains the application I want to run.  This does not seem to work though, FindClass simply returns a null.  I've narrowed it down to a problem with the classpath setting, like I said, because I can extract my jar file in the same directory as the executable and it will work.  Here is a subset of my code:

I've loosely been following this guide: http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/invocationApi/

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        void* jvmDllHandle;
        JNIEnv* jenv;
        JavaVM* jvm;
        JavaVMInitArgs args;
        JavaVMOption options[1];
        jclass cls;
        jmethodID mainMethod;
        jobjectArray appArgs;
        jstring arg0;

        assert( cygwin_internal( CW_SYNC_WINENV ) != 1UL );

        jvmDllHandle = LoadLibrary( "c:\\Path\\To\\Application\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll" );
        createJavaVM = dlsym( jvmDllHandle, "JNI_CreateJavaVM" );

        args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
        args.nOptions = 1;
        options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=c:\\Path\\To\\Application\\TheJarFile.jar";
        args.options = options;
        args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

        createJavaVM( &jvm, (void **) &jenv, &args );

        cls = (*jenv)->FindClass( jenv, "some/package/MainClass" );
        assert( cls != NULL );  // This fails.

        /// Omitted...

        return 0;
}
```

Tried using -classpath and -cp

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        void* jvmDllHandle;
        JNIEnv* jenv;
        JavaVM* jvm;
        JavaVMInitArgs args;
        JavaVMOption options[1];
        jclass cls;
        jmethodID mainMethod;
        jobjectArray appArgs;
        jstring arg0;

        assert( cygwin_internal( CW_SYNC_WINENV ) != 1UL );

        jvmDllHandle = LoadLibrary( "c:\\Path\\To\\Application\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll" );
        createJavaVM = dlsym( jvmDllHandle, "JNI_CreateJavaVM" );

        args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
        args.nOptions = 1;
        options[0].optionString = "-classpath c:\\Path\\To\\Application\\TheJarFile.jar";
        args.options = options;
        args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

        createJavaVM( &jvm, (void **) &jenv, &args );

        cls = (*jenv)->FindClass( jenv, "some/package/MainClass" );
        assert( cls != NULL );  // This fails.

        /// Omitted...

        return 0;
}
```

How am I specifying the classpath incorrectly?

Comment: did you actually look for the java classpath option?

Comment: What do you mean?  I tried using -classpath and -cp if that's what your talking about.

Comment: yes, that's what i'm talking about.  can you show that code?

Comment: I can't call java -classpath or java -cp.  I need to configure the Cygwin environment before launching the JVM so I can use some JNI libraries that require a POSIX layer.  So I needed to create my own launcher.

Comment: One of the comments in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059602/loading-multiple-jars-on-windows-jni-jni-createjavavm) mentioned there are sometimes issues with the windows file separator ('\'). Try the first example again using Unix style separators ('/')

Comment: Yeah, I noticed and tried that as well.

Comment: Have you tried not specifying the jar file explicitly and just the directory? How about exporting the CLASSPATH env variable instead? Your format looks right for the command, but JNI has some quirks, to say the least...

Comment: I just tried exporting CLASSPATH via setenv(...).  The odd thing is, if I extract the Jar file and specify the directory to which the JAR was extracted, it still fails.  I even had the launcher doing the unzip to the user's temporary directory and using that as the classpath, but it didn't work either.  It works fine if I extract the JAR to the same directory as the .exe.  I could probably do that in my actual code, but I'd rather just use the JAR or extract the JAR to the temporary directory.

Answer (score 3):

On x86-64, the Oracle Windows JDK headers define `jint` as `long`. This is 32 bits with Microsoft compilers (which the Oracle JDK is written for) but 64 bits with Cygwin gcc. Since `JavaVMInitArgs` contains some fields of this type, its binary layout is changed by this discrepancy.

I worked around this by providing a local `jni.h` header:

```c
#include "stdint.h"

#define __int64 int64_t
#define long int32_t
#include "jni_md.h"
#undef long

#include_next "jni.h"
```

I'm including only `jni_md.h` within the scope of the `long` redefinition because it doesn't include any other headers, whereas `jni.h` includes a couple of standard headers which we would not want to be affected as well.

To ensure this is always included ahead of the Oracle header, use the `-I` compiler option to add its directory to the `#include` path.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891478/error-when-compiling-in-cygwin