# When invoking JavaVM from C++ (using Cygwin) how can I load a JAR?

Tags: java, c++, bash, java-native-interface, cygwin

I'm writing an application in C++. I want to start JVM and call Java methods from this application. I'm running on Windows 10 using Cygwin.

According to the [Java Invocation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) page I believe I'm invoking JVM correctly; however, when I print the System Property "java.class.path" it shows as empty.

If I copy the class file to `$PWD/main/MyClass.class` everything works, but if I package up this class file into `$PWD/main.jar` and try to reference that the same way, then I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main/MyClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.MyClass
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

The output of the following program is:

```
Value of 'java/lang/System.getProperty(java.class.path)' is ''.
Value of 'java/lang/System.getProperty(user.dir)' is 'C:\Users\admin\java_from_cpp_stack\bin'.
Failed to find class 'main/MyClass'.
```

Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>

bool
printSysemProperty(JNIEnv* env, std::string property)
{
  std::string className = "java/lang/System";
  jclass cls = env->FindClass(className.c_str());
  if (cls == 0) {
    std::cout << "Failed to find class '" << className.c_str() << "'.\n";
    return false;
  }
  std::string methodName = "getProperty";
  jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, methodName.c_str(), "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
  if (mid == 0) {
    std::cout << "Failed to find method '" << className.c_str() << "." << methodName.c_str() << "'.\n";
    return false;
  }
  jstring cp = env->NewStringUTF(property.c_str());
  jstring val = (jstring)env->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls, mid, (jstring)cp);
  const char* valCStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(val, JNI_FALSE);
  std::cout << "Value of '" << className.c_str() << "." << methodName.c_str() << "(" << property.c_str() << ")' is '" << (char*)valCStr << "'.\n";
  return true;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Create JVM
  JavaVM* vm;  
  JNIEnv* env;  
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;  
  JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];  
  //options[0].optionString = (char*)"-Djava.class.path=.";
  //options[0].optionString = (char*)"-Djava.class.path=C:\\Users\\admin\\java_from_cpp_stack\\bin\\main.jar";
  //options[0].optionString = (char*)"-Djava.class.path=/cygdrive/c/Users/admin/java_from_cpp_stack/bin/main.jar";
  options[0].optionString = (char*)"-Djava.class.path=main.jar";
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;  
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;
  vm_args.options = options;  
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false; 
  int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);  
  delete options;
  if (ret != 0)
    std::cerr << "Failed to create JVM.\n";

  // Print System Properties
  bool rc = true;
  rc &= printSysemProperty( env, "java.class.path");
  rc &= printSysemProperty( env, "user.dir");
  if (!rc) {
    std::cout << "Printing system properties failed.\n";
    return rc;
  }

  // Call Static Method from JAR
  std::string className = "main/MyClass";
  jclass cls = env->FindClass(className.c_str());
  if (cls == 0) {
    std::cout << "Failed to find class '" << className.c_str() << "'.\n";
    return -3;
  }
  jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "hello", "()V");
  if (mid == 0) {
    std::cout << "Failed to find method '" << className.c_str() << ".hello'.\n";
    return -4;
  }
  std::cout << "Calling '" << className.c_str() << ".main'.\n";
  env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid);

  // Clean up
  vm->DestroyJavaVM();
  std::cout << "Complete.\n";
  return 0;

}
```

Here is the Java code:

```
package main;

public class MyClass {
  public MyClass() {
  }

  public static void hello() {
    System.out.println("From Java: Hello World!");
  }
}
```

Here is a BASH script I use to compile:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

rm -rf ./build
mkdir ./build

rm -rf ./bin/
mkdir ./bin/

g++ \
  -o ./bin/myprog \
  ./src/cpp/myprog.c \
  -D__int64=int64_t \
  -L/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/server/ \
  -ljvm \
  -I/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/include \
  -I/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/include/win32

/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javac \
  -Xlint:all \
  -Werror \
  -g \
  -verbose \
  -cp ./build \
  -sourcepath ./src/java \
  -d ./build \
  ./src/java/main/MyClass.java

/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/jar \
  cvf ./bin/main.jar \
  -C ./build \
  main/MyClass.class

#mkdir ./bin/main
#cp ./build/main/MyClass.class ./bin/main

cd ./bin
PATH=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/server/:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/:$PATH ./myprog
```

Comment: A low hanging check: did you check that "-Djava.class.path=main.jar" would resolve to $PWD/main/MyClass.class?

Comment: I think so (correct me if you mean something different) as `jar tf ./bin/main.jar` produces:

`META-INF/`

`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

`main/MyClass.class`

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of path resolution. Have you tried to pass the full path of the jar?

Comment: Ah. Well I have tried the following: `-Djava.class.path=C:\\Users\\admin\\java_from_cpp_stack\\bin\\main.jar` and that didn't work.

Comment: It seems the jar is not loaded by the application class loader. System is part of the bootstrap class loader so your c++ finds it. I would check how you are launching the jvm from c++

Comment: I just ran this on Linux and it worked! To me that means that the setup is correct. Now I need to figure out why, when I run from Cygwin, the java.class.path system property isn't getting set from the JavaVMOption.

Comment: Yes. It seems as if an env setting is missing. What you are doing is pretty straight forward

Comment: Does it tell you anything useful when you put `-Xcheck:jni` in `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`?

Comment: After I set `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` to `-Xcheck:jni` Java didn't give me any new information.  On a side note, I tried setting `CLASSPATH` to my JAR (in several different ways) and still the JVM launched from Cygwin compiled C++ could not find the class definitions.  I also tried running the application from a batch shell and I get the same error and the "-Djava.class.path=..." didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I think I remember something... namely that the VM doesn't copy the options. Try without the `delete options`. Maybe the other compilers leave the "deleted" memory alone while the cygwin one clears it.

Comment: Removing delete didn't help, thank you. I tried giving the path to main.jar as a URL and going through (remember I'm doing all of this from C++ using JNI) `ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);`. From here I called `loader.loadClass("main.MyClass", true);`. I tested to see if the Class actually loaded by using: `loader.getResource("main/MyClass.class");` which returns `jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/java_from_cpp_stack/bin/main.jar!/main/MyClass.class`. It looks like JVM can find my class and is looking inside the JAR; unfortunately, when I call `FindClass` I still get `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution is posted here:
[JNI JVM Invocation Classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869502/jni-jvm-invocation-classpath)

> On x86-64, the Oracle Windows JDK headers define jint as long. This is
>   32 bits with Microsoft compilers (which the Oracle JDK is written for)
>   but 64 bits with Cygwin gcc. Since `JavaVMInitArgs` contains some fields
>   of this type, its binary layout is changed by this discrepancy.

Also see:
[Error when compiling in cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891478/error-when-compiling-in-cygwin)

My fixes were:

1. Remove the `-D__int64=int64_t` from `g++` command line
2. Add the header file `jni_local.h`
3. Then `JavaVMInitArgs` were recognized.

The `src/cpp/jni_local.h` file contents are:

```
#include "stdint.h"

#define __int64 int64_t
#define long int32_t
#include "jni_md.h"
#undef long

#include_next "jni.h"
```

The `src/cpp/myprog.c` was reduced to:

```
#include "jni_local.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Create JVM
  JavaVM* vm;  
  JNIEnv* env;  
  JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;  
  JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];  
  options[0].optionString = (char*)"-Djava.class.path=myPackage.jar";
  vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;  
  vm_args.nOptions = 1;
  vm_args.options = options;  
  vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false; 
  int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);  
  delete options;
  if (ret != 0) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to create JVM.\n";
    return ret;
  }

  // Call Static Method from JAR
  std::string className = "myPackage/MyClass";
  jclass cls = env->FindClass(className.c_str());
  if (cls == 0) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to find class '" << className.c_str() << "'.\n";
    return -3;
  }
  jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "hello", "()V");
  if (mid == 0) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to find method '" << className.c_str() << ".hello'.\n";
    return -4;
  }
  std::cerr << "Calling 'myPackage." << className.c_str() << ".hello()'\n";
  env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid);

  // Clean up
  vm->DestroyJavaVM();
  std::cerr << "Complete.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The `src/java/myPackage/MyClass.java` was not changed.

The `run.sh` file was updated to have:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

rm -rf ./build
mkdir ./build

rm -rf ./bin/
mkdir ./bin/

g++ \
  -o ./bin/myprog \
  ./src/cpp/myprog.c \
  -L/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/server/ \
  -ljvm \
  -Isrc/cpp \
  -I/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/include \
  -I/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/include/win32

/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/javac \
  -Xlint:all \
  -Werror \
  -g \
  -verbose \
  -cp ./build \
  -sourcepath ./src/java \
  -d ./build \
  ./src/java/myPackage/MyClass.java

/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/jar \
  cvf ./bin/myPackage.jar \
  -C ./build \
  myPackage/MyClass.class

/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/jar tf ./bin/myPackage.jar

cd ./bin
PATH=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/bin/server/:/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/:$PATH ./myprog
```